# What is the normal system for $Ax$ when $A$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

> What is the normal system for $Ax$ when $A$ is orthogonal?

That is the exact wording of the question.

Can anybody help me with this?
I'm not sure what they are asking when they say "normal system". Is it referring to a perpendicular system? or just using normal in the layman's terms?

I know if $A$ is orthogonal, then $\Vert Ax\Vert=\Vert x \Vert$.
This is a question from Anton and Rorres in the orthogonal matrices chapter.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MrYouMath

Comment: Do you mean Anton and Rorres (not Torres)?

Comment: A little searching seems to indicate that the normal system or normal equation is $A^TA\vec{x}=A^Tb$.

Comment: Yes I meant Rorres sorry @Michael. Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBurr. After your help, I looked into the least square chapter in the book and it is a prominent equation in that chapter. I missed that chapter as I am not sure if I have to study it. But I will confirm that before the exam. Cheers.